# Are there Windows or Linux solutions which can backup any iOS app completely including its data?

Tags: ios, backup, applications

Are there Windows/Linux solutions which can backup any iOS app completely including its data?

Suppose I have an iOS app X installed.

If such a backup program exists, I want to run it to backup X and its data to my computer. Then suppose I reset my iPhone to factory settings. Then I run the backup software to restore my backup, and my iPhone should have its app X back where it was including its settings and data.

I want such a backup program to work for any app, not just for apps like WhatsApp which have their data in a known format.

If such a program doesn't exist, can you recommend one which comes closest to it (i.e. recommend the best app backup software for iOS you can think of)?

On desktop I have Linux and Windows.

Note: Also, I don't want to use iCloud.

Comment: You still can backup locally to your Mac.

Comment: @nohillside I only have Windows and Linux how would I go about performing such a backup?

Comment: Have you tried [backing up via iTunes](https://support.apple.com/guide/itunes/back-up-your-iphone-ipad-or-ipod-touch-itns3280/windows)?

Comment: Might be worth mentioning this in the question. Not sure whether iTunes or its successor in Windows will allow to backup locally though.

Comment: I changed the title slightly. Apps on iOS are sandboxed, so a backup solution *must* run on another device.

Comment: @nohillside, I successfully backed up an iPhone4S, 7 plus, and a 12 on Windows 10 (VBox) using iTunes all within the last 2 to 3 months.  As far as I know, iTunes is still current for Windows.

Comment: @Allan I just performed a backup now using iTunes inside a VMware Windows. The backup takes 6 GB. Any idea what it contains? Does it contain all app data and settings? Thanks!

Comment: In a single word: everything.  Everything  on your iPhone from the OS to all app data is backed up. . This backup method was one of the only ways to “downgrade” iOS to a previous version because it was so thorough.

Comment: @Allan Looks like it will be replaced with Apple Devices soon (still in beta) on Windows 11: https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/apple-devices-preview/9NP83LWLPZ9K?hl=en-us&gl=de&rtc=1